# Intranet compatibility mode overrides to IE-7 default

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, compatibility

I am using the tags and code which is supported by IE-11. But when the same code is run on Intranet site, document mode gets set to IE-7 and the page breaks. Our system admin has disabled the modification to uncheck compatibility mode.

I tried setting the below line in my jsp page immediately after `<head>` tag, but their is no effect.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge">
```

I am using websphere server 8.0.9 and java. 
Need help or insight as to what else we can do to achieve this?

Comment: If we ask the system admin to make us available the option to uncheck compatibilty view setting then it will be applicable to the entire organization. I am not sure, how many websites would break if this setting is disabled? I have already completed all the development now and at last moment facing this bloody issue. This is like going back 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the above line to below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This seems to be working for me now. I could see the document mode changing to Edge and page working. I have included this right from index page to the corresponding page.